# Select the "select all" check box from second pull down list

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath

I am new to working with Xpath, and this first experience is dealing with one that doesn't have id, nor name.

I am trying to select the "select all" check box from the second pull down list on top.  Since this is on a secured network, I don't know how to pull the code, a snapshot is attached instead.

[image]

The action is to be performed in Phython 2.7.  I have the Selenium driver loaded and able to open the page, just can't make this selection.

```
dropdown=driver.find_element_by_xpath("    ")
Select(dropdown).select_by_visible_text("Select all")
```

Comment: Something went wrong with my original post, the picture link was inserted in the middle of the text.  Last couple lines should be:  dropdown=driver.find_element_by_xpath("<xpath I am looking for>") and Select(dropdown).select_by_visible_text("Select all")

Answer (score 0):

This is not a `<select>` element, so `Select()` class wouldn't work here. You should try as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath (".//label[normalize-space(.)='Select all']/input").click()
```

Or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label.checkbox > input[value='multiselect-all']").click()
```